# B2C Graph API Update User, UserPrincipalName as an email: URL does not support plus (+) sign in email?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-b2c

I was testing a PATCH request to the Graph API here: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}` to update `accountEnabled` attribute.

The documentation states that this is the format:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

I did a POST request earlier and successfully made a user with `userPrincipalName` as an email (within identities array for B2C user), that is something like `emailaddress+1@gmail.com`

When I try to put that in the URL as the `userPrincipalName`, I get `unknownError` back from the graph API. After some experimenting, I found it was the `+` in the URL which would make sense. However, a `UrlEncode` to `%2b` for `+` also does not work. Encoding the @ symbol even throws an error by the API?

Is this not supported by the API URL? Within the B2C Users panel in Azure portal, all I see for user principal name is that email I made them with that original POST request. The only solution I can think of is to not allow users to sign up in the first place with that + sign in their email. Using User/object ID is not possible in my case.

Comment: There is no way to create a B2C user with their UPN attribute as gmail. You need to search /users and filter on the identities attribute for B2C users.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT I was not being clear enough here. I am originally making the B2C user using the identities array with the original create user API call. I recall an error early in my learning which told me directly setting that attribute outside the identities array returned an error from the API. However, in B2C Users panel this shows up under identities as a `User Principal Name`. This is not the same User Principal Name as the one the documentation is referring to? I see no other User Principal Name within the user profile in AD B2C. Just an object ID.

Comment: UPN in azure portal for a B2C user object, refers to emailAddress or username in the identities collection of that user object. We used UPN there because it’s reusing AAD UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allowed characters for userPrincipalName are `A - Z`, `a - z`, `0 - 9`, `' . - _ ! # ^ ~`. Read more about username policies in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-policy#userprincipalname-policies-that-apply-to-all-user-accounts).

It would be interesting to know if indeed you were able to create a user with a character in the userPrincipalName that is not allowed or if the API ignored/removed/converted the `+` sign.
Can you get the `Id` of the user by searching on the Azure Portal? Then you can [Get the user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and see the value of `userPrincipalName`.

Comment: And this applies to B2C as well? Can't find the term B2C in that article at all. Yes, it allows the Identity UPN to be any @ email. Our B2C directory is filled with these. In my original create user calls using this: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users, in the `identities` array I do `signInType` `emailAddress`. It even allowed the +1 in the email for that original call, but can't access it with an update request with +1 or encoding in url as question discusses. https://prnt.sc/laD3rQsWca8r. I did tag this as azure-ad-b2c but this should have been more clear on my part.

Comment: UPN attribute is auto generated for b2c users.